# Targeting in Ajax/jQuery tab system

Tags: jquery

I'm planning an Ajax tab system using jQuery based on the code at [this website](http://www.ajaxblender.com/howto-create-custom-jquery-tabs.html) (see the demo [here](http://www.ajaxblender.com/article-sources/jquery/ajax-tabs-example/)).

It's a good foundation  which I've been able to work with despite my rather limited knowledge. However, I'm wondering if anyone has ideas about how to extend the functionality slightly, to allow tabs to be targeted from within the content container.

For example: Tab 1 has text associated with it, and I'd like to be able to include a hyperlink within that text that will switch you to Tab 3 (much as if you'd actually clicked on "Tab 3" itself).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would be better if you could show us what you have already done (in terms of code)

Answer (score 0):

Just assign the link to the tab, that you are targeting. Assign this link to the element, on which you want to set the link.

Jquery-ui tabs does it very easily, alongwith other great functionalities as well..

I recommend that you should be using jquery-ui tabs.

Let me know if I am clear.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The problem with jQuery UI tabs is that it is designed to be "dropped in". I would like my tab system to look quite different from the theme, and I don't want to have to try to overwrite the default styles with a whole lot of messy '!important' hacks.

Comment: Just assign the link to the tab, that you are targeting. Assign this link to the element, on which you want to set the link.

this is  meant for your tab-content that you are using.


If you have content like Link to Tab-3 within tab-1, then you can always set html like this:

<a href="./tabs/tab-3.html">Link to Tab-3</a>

Can you please check this way.

Comment: I am aware that the jQuery UI tabs plugin comes with link targeting. As I stated, my problem with that plugin is that it also comes with a lot of useless CSS junk that makes customisation harder. Anyway, I have found another plugin that does what I want, without the limitations of jQuery UI tabs: [jQuery EasyTabs](http://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/).